# Reflection on method parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection

Take the following class:

```
class Automator
  def fill_specific_form(fields)
    fields.each_pair do |key, value|
      puts "Setting '#{key}' to '#{value}'"
    end
  end
end

a = Automator.new
a.fill_specific_form :first_name => "Mads", :last_name => "Mobæk"

# => Setting 'first_name' to 'Mads'
# => Setting 'last_name' to 'Mobæk'
```

Is it possible to do the same without a hash? Since all parameters are required, I want a method with the following signature:

```
fill_specific_form(first_name, last_name)
```

In my mind this would be possible by having the method body reflect and iterate over its parameters, thus achieving the same result.

How would you implement this? Does a pattern/idiom for this exist already? Two obvious benefits would be parameter information in IDEs and not having to check if all hash keys are supplied.

What I want to avoid is:

```
puts "Setting first_name to #{first_name}"
puts "Setting last_name to #{last_name}"
# and so on
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Ruby - print the variable name and then its value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603617/ruby-print-the-variable-name-and-then-its-value)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Is there a way to return a method parameter names in ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2452077/#2452322).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set no other local variables inside the method, `local_variables` will give you a list of the method's parameter names (if you do set other variables you can just call `local_variables` first thing and remember the result). So you can do what you want with `local_variables`+`eval`:

```
class Automator
  def fill_specific_form(first_name, last_name)
    local_variables.each do |var|
      puts "Setting #{var} to #{eval var.to_s}"
    end
  end
end

Automator.new().fill_specific_form("Mads", "Mobaek")
```

Be however advised that this is pure evil.

And at least for your example

```
puts "Setting first_name to #{first_name}"
puts "Setting last_name to #{last_name}"
```

seems much more sensible.

You could also do `fields = {:first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name}` at the beginning of the method and then go with your `fields.each_pair` code.

Comment: Pure evil is not intended and not what I want. Just curious if there was a way to do this. I will test your suggestions and get back to you

Comment: fields = {:first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name} is what I want. Thank you.

Comment: I tried with Ruby 1.9.3, and you have to do #{eval var.to_s} to get it to work, otherwise you get a TypeError: can't convert Symbol into String

Comment: @JavidJamae Yes, they've changed local_variables from an array of strings to an array of symbols in 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand. Do you want to receive all parameters within a single array?

```
def fill_specific_form *args
    #Process args
end
```

Comment: Not quite. This only gets the values passed. By using explicit parameter names matching the name of a form element, I could then set name = value. See sepp2k's answer

Answer (score 0):

To reflect on a method's (or `Proc`'s) parameters, you can use `Proc#parameters`, `Method#parameters` or `UnboundMethod#parameters`:

```
->(m1, o1=nil, *s, m2, &b){}.parameters
# => [[:req, :m1], [:opt, :o1], [:rest, :s], [:req, :m2], [:block, :b]]
```

However, in your case, I don't see why you need reflection, since you *already know* the names of the parameters anyway.

Comment: Is this new in 1.9.2? This doesn't work for me in 1.8.7 or 1.9.1.

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes, `Proc#parameters` is new in 1.9.2.