# Ruby - get hash of method parameters and their current value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way in Ruby to get the current method's list of arguments and their current value (during method run)? As in:

```
def foo(a, b, c)
    arg_vals = __method__params__
    return arg_vals
end

 x = foo(10,20,30) #returns {a:10, b:20, c:30}
```

(Background: I want this for my logging library, so that from any point I could call: )

```
my_logger(__method__, __method__params__)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but this is close:

```
def test(arg1, arg2)
    args = local_variables.inject({}) { |c, i| c[i] = eval(i); c }
    puts args.inspect
end

test('hello', 'world')
```

output:

```
{"args"=>nil, "arg1"=>"hello", "arg2"=>"world"}
```

Interactive version: http://repl.it/QTi

Also note that if called near the end of a method, it can give you insight into all of the local variables inside the method, which can be either a benefit or annoying depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: No it is not correct way to meet OP's need. Only answer pf this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211813/is-there-a-way-to-access-method-arguments-in-ruby