# Memoizing functions with multiple parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, memoization

I'm wondering if there is a more "Ruby-like" way to memoize functions with multiple parameters in Ruby. Here's a way that I came up with that works but not sure if it's the best approach:

```
@cache = {}
def area(length, width)  #Just an example, caching is worthless for this simple function
  key = [length.to_s, width.to_s].join(',')
  if @cache[key]
    puts 'cache hit!'
    return @cache[key]
  end
  @cache[key] = length * width
end

puts area 5, 3
puts area 5, 3
puts area 4, 3
puts area 3, 4
puts area 4, 3
```

The parameters are joined with a comma which is then used as a key for storage in the `@cache` variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you do not need to print `Cache hit!` than I would do something like this:

```
def area(length, width)
  @cache ||= {}
  @cache["#{length},#{width}"] ||= length * width
end
```

Or if you need some output, but a `Cache miss!` is fine too:

```
def area(length, width)
  @cache ||= {}

  @cache.fetch("#{length},#{width}") do |key| 
    puts 'Cache miss!'
    @cache[key] = length * width
  end
end
```

If you want to accept even more arguments you might want to use something like this:

```
def area(*args)
  @cache ||= {}
  @cache[args] ||= args.inject(:*)
end
```

Comment: Let's say I change the function to accept three arguments. Is there a good way to automate the generation of the key?

Comment: Your code is 2x faster than my code even with print statement stripped out.

Comment: You mean if you used common named arguments, but do not want to list them all? There might be a way: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31234292/2483313). But would use it...

Comment: I guess hard-coded it shall be. That looks ugly. Is there a Ruby gem that handles multiple parameter memoization?

Comment: If performance is an issue, hashing the arguments and using an integer for a key would be far better. Something like `length.hash ^ width.hash`. It could also be easily adapted to handle variable number of arguments: `args.inject { |r, n | r ^ n.hash }`. The likelihood of a hash collision would be super rare. You could always throw in a prime number to reduce those odds even more.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the array directly:

```
def area(length, width)
  key = [length, width]
  if @cache[key]
    puts 'cache hit!'
    return @cache[key]
  end
  @cache[key] = length * width
end
```

Or use nested hashes:

```
def area(length, width)
  c = (@cache[length] ||= {})
  if c[width]
    puts 'cache hit!'
    return c[width]
  end
  c[width] = length * width
end
```

Comment: I'd be nervous about the thread-safety of all of these, but especially so the last one.

Comment: Nifty trick with the first one. So the array automatically gets converted to a string? What's the issue with threading, exactly? What can go wrong? Two different cache data structures will be built?

Comment: No, the array isn't automatically converted into a string. There is no need to do that. Because every object can be used as a hash key: symbols, integer, or even huge complex data structures.

Comment: In general at best you could have multiple threads calculating the same value... but with the nested hash form one call could clear out a different width's calculation [for the same length], for example.

Comment: I did some benchmarking. My original function with the join is twice as fast as using an object for a key.

Answer (score 2):

On **Ruby 2.7 and up**, positional arguments and keyword arguments are isolated which has an impact on how to implement multi-argument memoization. For a generic implementation, I'd do something like this:

```rb
def my_method(*args, **kwargs)
  (@my_method_cache ||= {})[args.hash ^ kwargs.hash] ||= begin
    (...)
  end
end
```

Replace `(...)` with the expensive calculation done by `my_method`.

Answer (score 1):

While @spickermann's answer is good and @matthewd's answer touches upon it, the elephant in the room is memoization of falsey values. Naive `||=` will not cut it.

Consider:

```
def memoises_truthy(arg1, arg2)
  @memo ||= {}
  memo_key = "#{arg1.hash}_#{arg2.hash}"

  @memo[memo_key] ||= begin
    puts "Crunching #{arg1} && #{arg2}"
    arg1 && arg2 
  end
end

> memoises_truthy(:a, :b)
Crunching a && b
=> :b
> memoises_truthy(:a, :b)
=> :b
> memoises_truthy(false, false)
Crunching false && false
=> false
> memoises_truthy(false, false)
Crunching false && false # noo, cache miss!
=> false
```

A more robust approach is to check the presence of the cache key, even if the value is falsey.

```
def memoises_all(arg1, arg2)
  @memo ||= {}
  memo_key = "#{arg1.hash}_#{arg2.hash}"

  return @memo[memo_key] if @memo.key?(memo_key) # a simple guard for cache hit.
  
  @memo[memo_key] = begin
    puts "Crunching #{arg1} && #{arg2}"
    arg1 && arg2 
  end
end

> memoises_all(:a, :b)
Crunching a && b
=> :b
> memoises_all(:a, :b)
=> :b
 memoises_all(false, false)
Crunching false && false
=> false
memoises_all(false, false)
=> false
```

Comment: Nice catch!  I think using an array as the hash key lookup is possible too! and from [this article](https://michaeljherold.com/articles/memoization-in-ruby/#:~:text=pass%20an%20Array%20of%20objects%20as%20a%20Hash%20key) might cover the same catch?

Like this: `memo_key = [arg1.hash, arg2.hash]`