# Can I access keyword parameters of a method as a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have several methods with keyword parameters which call *other methods* with the same parameters. Currently I have to pass each parameter manually. Is there a way I can access all the keyword parameters as a Hash and pass that down directly?

Sample code -

```rb
def method1(arg1:, arg2:)
  # do something specific to method1
  result = executor1(arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2)
  # do something with result
end

def method2(arg3:, arg4:, arg5:, arg6:)
  # do something specific to method2
  result = executor2(arg3: arg3, arg4: arg4, arg5: arg5, arg6: arg6)
  # do something with result
end

def method3(arg7:)
  # do something specific to method3
  result = executor3(arg7: arg7)
  # do something with result
end
```

Can I do something which would change the code to -

```rb
def method1(arg1:, arg2:)
  # do something specific to method1
  args = method1_args_as_a_hash
  result = executor1(args)
  # do something with result
end

def method2(arg3:, arg4:, arg5:, arg6:)
  # do something specific to method2
  args = method2_args_as_a_hash
  result = executor2(args)
  # do something with result
end

def method3(arg7:)
  # do something specific to method3
  args = method3_args_as_a_hash
  result = executor3(args)
  # do something with result
end
```

Context - The number of these keyword arguments has grown quite large in my codebase and passing them as is (or sometimes with slight modifications) to `executorX` methods is making the code file too big and difficult to read. I unfortunately cannot change the signature of `methodX` methods since I don't have access to every codebase they are used in and also cannot risk breaking any of their consumers. I do have full control over their logic and over `executorX` methods. My aim is to refactor this code to reduce the number of lines and improve the readability.

Thanks!

Comment: `method(__method__).parameters`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211813/is-there-a-way-to-access-method-arguments-in-ruby

Comment: Passing around a huge number of arguments can be a code smell. You might consider encapsulating those values in a single object and pass that around. Or maybe convert the methods into instance methods of that object.

Comment: BTW, [keyword argument](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) values can be omitted in newer Ruby versions, i.e. instead of `executor1(arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2)` you can write `executor1(arg1:, arg2:)` – not perfect but a little more compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done but is pretty clunky.

You can instrospect on a method with the `method` method and get it's signature and then use `binding` to get the local variables with the same name:

```
def foo(bar:, baz:)
  params = method(__method__).parameters # [[:keyreq, :bar], [:keyreq, :baz]]
  params.each_with_object({}) do |(_, name), hash|
    hash[name] = binding.local_variable_get(name) 
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):025:0> foo(bar: 1, baz: 2)
=> {:bar=>1, :baz=>2}
```

`__method__` is a special magic method that contains the name of the current method.

Just beware that extracting that if you want to avoid repeating this all over your code base that you would need to pass the binding object to your other method as well as the name of the method.

```
module Collector
  # @param [Binding] context
  # @param [String|Symbol] method_name
  # @return [Hash] 
  def collect_arguments(context, method_name)
    params = context.reciever.method(method_name).parameters
    params.each_with_object({}) do |(_, name), hash|
      hash[name] = context.local_variable_get(name) 
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Thing
  include Collector

  def method1(arg1:, arg2:)
    # do something specific to method1
    args = collect_arguments(binding, __method__)
    result = executor1(**args)
    # do something with result
  end
end
```

Comment: I have no idea why Ruby doesn't have something like the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in JS which would make this a lot smoother.

Comment: While this is quite an impressive exercise in meta-programming, you should try hard to not need this in production. Apart from being quite slow, it is quite obscure and may lead to hard-to-debug issues when used wrong (or just when used with variable arguments) . The more common approach of accepting any arguments with `**` or `**kwargs` and then just forwarding them is much more commonly used and will thus be more familiar to others reading the code.

Comment: @HolgerJust I 100% agree. If there is any other option then take it - this is really just intended as a lemonade making excercise if you really have to make do.

Answer (score 5):

When you always want to pass all keyword arguments from the method call to the nested method call, then using the double splat operator (`**`) should work for you:

```
def method1(**)
  # do something specific to method1
  result = executor1(**)
  # do something with result
end
```

Comment: Hm, don't even need to name it, `**kwargs`? TIL

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If all you're doing is forwarding, you can take `...`, `*`, `**`, or `&` as unnamed arguments and forward them using the same syntax. `*` forwards positional, `**` forwards named, `&` forwards a block, and `...` forwards everything in one go.

Comment: This does unfortunately require changing the signature of the methods. While you could kind of change the signature to `method1(**kwargs)`  and allow it to be called the same way it is currently called you would have to add checks to see that the required keys are there to have the same functionality. It also introduces the subtile change that the method now takes any keyword arguments instead of just a limited list of named keyword arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure if the monstrosity in my answer is any better though.