# Where does the extra array come from?

Tags: arrays, ruby, data-structures, hash

This question is a continuation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39447568/3293148).

Below I am trying to reproduce the answer with the real data structure, but I get an extra array for some reason and the elements are swapped.

**Question**

The two outputs should be the same, so can anyone see  what I am doing wrong?

This is correct:

```
require 'pp'

a = {"A"=>1, "B"=>1, "C"=>1}
b = {"A"=>1, "B"=>1, "D"=>1, "E"=>1}
c = {"D"=>1, "E"=>1, "F"=>1}

keys = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
a.each_key { |k| keys[k] << :a }
b.each_key { |k| keys[k] << :b }
c.each_key { |k| keys[k] << :c }
pp keys
```

which gives

```
{"A"=>[:a, :b],
 "B"=>[:a, :b],
 "C"=>[:a],
 "D"=>[:b, :c],
 "E"=>[:b, :c],
 "F"=>[:c]}
```

Here is the real data structure,

```
groups = {
  "a" => {"A"=>1, "B"=>1, "C"=>1},
  "b" => {"A"=>1, "B"=>1, "D"=>1, "E"=>1},
  "c" => {"D"=>1, "E"=>1, "F"=>1}
}

keys2 = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
groups.each { |k,v| keys2[k] << v.keys }
pp keys2
```

which gives the incorrect output

```
{"a"=>[["A", "B", "C"]], "b"=>[["A", "B", "D", "E"]], "c"=>[["D", "E", "F"]]}
```

Comment: @Stefan Yes, that also puzzles me. I can't see why they get swapped either.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes: " I can't see why they get swapped either" - because of the same reason. Code in the two snippets is totally different and does different things. Try some debug printing to see what happens at each line and step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your innermost structure hasn't changed, the `each_key` part should be almost identical, i.e.:

```
a.each_key { |k| keys[k] << :a }
```

But `a` now refers to one of your nested hashes and `:a` to its name:

```
hash.each_key { |k| keys2[k] << name }
```

`name` and `hash` refer to the keys and values in `group`:

```
groups = {
  "a" => {"A"=>1, "B"=>1, "C"=>1},
# ^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# name            hash
```

(Note that you can pick any variable name, `name` and `hash` are just examples.)

Putting it all together:

```
require 'pp'

keys2 = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

groups.each do |name, hash|
  hash.each_key { |k| keys2[k] << name }
end

pp keys2
```

Output:

```
{"A"=>["a", "b"],
 "B"=>["a", "b"],
 "C"=>["a"],
 "D"=>["b", "c"],
 "E"=>["b", "c"],
 "F"=>["c"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Where does the extra array come from?

Here. You're pushing it yourself.

```
keys2[k] << v.keys
```

Also, this part is different than what you do in the first snippet. If you're gonna do comparisons, do them right.  Minimize differences. If you do the same thing (`.each_key`, etc.), the structures will be the same.